# Apple Health Data Source Order

Tags: ios, healthkit

My app collects data such as steps using an activity tracker. I send this data to the Apple Health app. Everything works, but by default the iPhone would prioritize its own gathered data on steps over the data I provided.

Is there a way to programmatically change this order? It would be OK, if this was accompanied by an alert popping up. That would be much better than having to explain to the user where to change this setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no HealthKit API to change source order.

Comment: Well that's just annoying :( Thanks though.